# Hyperledger Fabric return json in shim.Error()

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am using `Hyperledger Fabric` for implementing blockchain and using `Golang` for writing `chaincode`.

I am able to send `JSON` in `shim.Success()` since it ask for byte array.
The issue is I am not able to send `JSON` in `shim.Error()`. I am using `node.js` sdk. It returns me a response with the following string

```
"chaincode error (status: 500, message: The email or password you have entered is wrong.)"
```

Is there any mechanism to parse this response? I want to get value of status and message. Please let me know if it possible.

If anyone knows how to send JSON in `shim.Error()` please comment or submit an answer.

Any help/comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
shim.error(new Error("Stringified JSON"));
```

or alternatively use

```
try {
  // Do Something
  throw new Error(JSON.stringify(errorJsonObject)); // Throw error wrapped in Error Object
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return shim.error(err);
}
```

Comment: shim.Error() accepts string argument. Not Error. I am using golang for chaincode